# What are the origins of: to “bleed something”?

Tags: etymology, expressions

I've come across the [answer about what it means to bleed something](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8259/what-does-to-bleed-something-mean) but am having a hard time finding its origin. What was the original thing that was bled and in what context was it used?

Comment: Okay, so right now it appears to be a battle to the references  between Feral Oink and Ham and Bacon.

Comment: If one says "they tried to bleed the [sickness]", then that is a reference to blood-letting, surely.  But otherwise, and as in the link you posted, a phrase is not being turned: It's a natural comparison, slowly and steadily dying from blood loss and steady economic downturn.  In a much more severe and urgent tone, one could say they were "hemorrhaging jobs" (hemorrhage is bleeding).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Cambridge Dictionary of American Idioms](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=ytJNRDL0zDgC&pg=PA33&lpg=PA33&dq=bleed%20something%20origin&source=bl&ots=WKE2uSnC37&sig=jMSiJSqtBT_8addNOqlZ78MTRx8&hl=en&ei=s4oaTvbvJMPqmAXNp6kT&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=5&ved=0CDsQ6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=bleed%20something%20origin&f=false) explain this

> bleed somebody/something dry
>
> to use up everything someone or something
>   has available
>
> The city is losing money at a rate that eventually will
>   bleed it dry. I'm worried that the medical bills will bleed my parents
>   dry.
>
> **Etymology: based on the idea of a person losing so much blood that they die**

This fits with the usage of "bleed something" as *a negative and damaging one*, and not therapeutic. This is pretty much what [@Robusto's answer to your related question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8259/what-does-to-bleed-something-mean/8260#8260) states.

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be a good deal of confusion in the answers here, and in the answers to the older question referenced by this questioner between at least two different ways "to bleed something":

> [*actor causing bleeding*]    bleeds    [*object from which something flows*]
>   Examples:
>   - A 17th century physician bleeds the patient to cure the disease.
>   - Last, the plumber bleeds the pipes.
>   - Losing money will bleed the city dry.

versus

> [*subject from which something flows*]    bleeds    [*material which flows*]
>   Example:
>   - Detroit bleeds manufacturing jobs.

The original question was about the latter kind of usage, and as best I can tell, this question is about that also.

So, the metaphorical use of *to bleed* seems to stretch into the distant past.  In the second kind of usage, the earliest example the *Oxford English Dictionary* gives is this line from Shakespeare's *Winter's Tale* (V. ii. 88):

> Shee did (with an Alas) I would faine say, bleed Teares; for I am sure, my heart wept blood.

Answer (score -1):

I would say that it refers to the practice of blood letting using leaches.
Physicians of days past, I need to find an exact time-dated reference for you, would bleed patients of "harmful humours". The idea was that blood loss would cure the patient of his ailment.

Summary, w/specific answers to your question:

- What was the original thing that was bled? A human being.
- In what context was it used? By medical practitioners (and the general public) of the 14th-19th centuries, in reference to a healer/ physician method for treating illness.

*Side note:* This also why physicians themselves were referred to as leaches, but not in a pejorative way, i.e. connoting fee-gouging behavior.